# Delphi2006 - How to create in DLL a message pump for a new window in a thread?

Tags: forms, delphi, dll, messaging, delphi-2006

I have multithreaded application that loads my custom dll.
In this dll I need to create a window.
I'm doing it by creating new thread and inside it I'm trying to create this window, but I have got error that tells me: `EInvalidOperation - Canvas does not allow drawing`.

By searching in the net, I have discovered that I need custom message pump for that thread.
So, my question is, how properly do this?

What I do now is:
- external app is loading dll
- than this app in separte thread is calling `Init` function from dll
- `Init` function creates thread
- `TMyThread` is declared as:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    Form: TMyForm;
    FParentHWnd: HWND;
    FRunning: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(parent_hwnd: HWND); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(parent_hwnd: HWND);
begin
  inherited Create(False); // run after create
  FreeOnTerminate:=True;
  FParentHWnd:=parent_hwnd;
  FRunning:=False;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  parent_hwnd: HWND;
  Msg: TMsg;
  XRunning: LongInt;
begin
  if not Terminated then begin
    try
      try
        parent_hwnd:=FParentHWnd;

        Form:=TMyForm.Create(nil); // <-- here is error
        Form.Show;

        FRunning:=True;

        while FRunning do begin
          if PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) then begin
            if Msg.Message <> WM_QUIT then
              Application.ProcessMessages
            else
              break;
          end;
          Sleep(1);
          XRunning:=GetProp(parent_hwnd, 'XFormRunning');
          if XRunning = 0 then
            FRunning:=False;
        end;
      except
        HandleException; // madExcept
      end;
    finally
      Terminate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The exception `EInvalidOperation - Canvas does not allow drawing` is fired before thread reaches my existing message pump code.

What do I do wrong or what is the right way to make it work?
Thanks for any help.

---

To create second GUI thread in a DLL, I must do things exactly as in standard application.
Can anyone confirm my thinking?

In the DLL `begin...end.` section I do:

```
begin
  Application.CreateForm(THiddenForm, HiddenForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

In the `TMyThread.Execute` I must do:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  if not Terminated then begin
    try
      try
        Application.CreateForm(TMyForm, Form);

        ???? how to make a thread that has remained in this place until you close this window ???
      except
        HandleException; // madExcept
      end;
    finally
      Terminate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Is this the right way? Could it be that simple?

Comment: Hmm.. does the DLL have its own TApplication instance?  IIRC, this is the only way to achieve what you seem to want - one process with two GUI threads.  I have done this before, just cannot remember the details :(

Comment: I think so, it does when it uses Forms.pas.

Comment: @MartinJames: Maybe you remember where and how I must create these two GUI threads? Or maybe you have some code to ilustrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier (a year ago) I stated this: `"To create second GUI thread in a DLL, I must do things exactly as in standard application"`.

This is `exactly` what everybody who is searching for this solution should do.
Let me explain, step by step:

1. we must add our application object to our thread:

   ```
   type  
     TMyThread = class(TThread)  
   private  
     ThreadApplication: TApplication;
   ```
2. now some modification to definition of `procedure TMyThread.Execute;`

   ```
   procedure TMyThread.Execute;  
   begin  
     if not Terminated then begin  
       try  
         ThreadApplication:=TApplication.Create(nil);  
         try  
           ThreadApplication.Initialize;  
           ThreadApplication.CreateForm(TMyForm, Form);  
           ThreadApplication.Run;
         finally  
           ThreadApplication.Free;
         end;  
       finally  
         Terminate;  
       end;  
     end;  
   end;
   ```
3. so, this is it, now we have message pump in a second GUI thread in a DLL.

Recently I found confirmation to this solution in a Delphi-Jedi blog, wrote by Christian Wimmer:
http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/05/27/winlogon-notification-package/

Thank You very much.

Comment: Link to delphi-jedi-net is dead.

Comment: sorry, but it seems that delphi-jedi.net is no more available on internet, but You can see archive version of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20080528182519/http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/05/27/winlogon-notification-package/, unfortunately this site didn't archived the attachements, where You should see LogoAppThread.pas for clarification, but i have found this: http://read.pudn.com/downloads134/sourcecode/delphi_control/571808/Winlogon/LogoAppThread.pas__.htm

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to run a message queue in a thread is as follows:

```
procedure PerformThreadLoop;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) and not Terminated do begin
    Try
      TranslateMessage(Msg);
      DispatchMessage(Msg);
    Except
      Application.HandleException(Self);
    End;
  end;
end;
```

And in your thread procedure would look like this:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute
begin
  InitialiseWindows;
  PerformThreadLoop;
end;
```

All that said, what you are attempting is not going to work. You appear to be trying to use VCL components away from the main thread. That is specifically not allowed. The VCL's threading model dictates that all VCL code is run on the main thread. Your attempts to create a VCL form away from the main thread are doomed to failure.

---

I would question your desire to create a new thread. A Delphi DLL can show VCL forms provided that it runs those forms out of the thread that loaded and called the DLL. You can call `Show` from that thread and show a modeless form. This means that you are relying on the host application's message queue to deliver messages to your windows. By and large this can be made to work. If your form is modal then you can simply call `ShowModal` and the form will be serviced by the standard Delphi modal message loop.

So my advice to you is to keep all your GUI in the host app's GUI thread. If your DLL is expected to show GUI, and is also expected to do that away from the host app's GUI thread then you are in trouble. But I think that's highly unlikely to be the case.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. I need to make forms outside of the host application UI thread and it must be based on Delphi VCL. So, I should title this question `how to make second UI thread in a DLL`, perhaps. I know that this is possible, but I think that nobody can explain how do that, especially in Delphi.

Comment: What do you mean, I know that this is possible? Are you fully aware of the VCL's threading model?

Comment: I think I do. Some time ago I did DLL that make forms, but simple use of `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` won't work because forms don't get CM_message's at all.

Comment: That's not true. Those messages will be delivered fine. They are after all just messages. You can call ProcessMessages if you prefer. But the bigger problem, the one you won't face, is that you cannot run VCL forms outside the main thread. That's well known.

Comment: The DLL doesn't have a main thread as such. The DLL's initialization will run out of the thread which calls `LoadLibrary` to load your DLL. You are then creating a `TThread` which lives in a different thread. So you've got VCL objects in two different threads which is against the rules.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the trick is to have separate TApplication objects for the two GUI threads.  If you do that, the problem with the VCL disappears becauuse there are, effectively, two VCL's in one process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - though to be fair, I haven't tried that since D5, but it did work.

Comment: @MartinJames You need more than that. You need separate instances of the global variables too.

Comment: @MartinJames: to me it seems that you have knowladge about how to have second TApplication object running from DLL, please dig out your old projects and share with us, what is the key to complite the topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - what can I say?  I tried it, it worked.  Whether it would be reliable for all operations, or over a long run, I don't know.

Comment: I don't know what vars are global, ie. not encapsulated in TApplication?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think that You have on your mind that no VCL window cannot be made outside of calling/runnig thread, windows can't create messages queue for other than for this thread that creates window.

Comment: @Nev You seem convinced that you can do this. So just do it! Use the message loop in my answer.

Comment: Yes I am, but what You proposed, it seems is not that what I need, because I already do it this way, and I have `EInvalidOperation - Canvas does not allow drawing` exception only right after trying to create window. For me it looks like during window create some messages are sent for setting some variables to specific state, but there is no message loop that can do something with it, so I must figure it out, how to do it correctly.

Comment: Hi, last 9 hours I am trying to make this working and now must say that I found several methods to do this. Later I will post my results. But there is one thing that I can't understand. When window is created sometimes I've got `EInvalidOperation` exception. Now I can say that it is related with `TCanvas.Handle` of window. I don't understand why it is equal to zero when it shouldn't be.

Comment: That's the thing with threading bugs. They don't always manifest. Trial and error is never the way to go. You need to understand the threading model from first principles.

Comment: To me it looks like bug in VCL, it occurs when newly created form is loading its resources.

Comment: Those are the sorts of errors you get when you break the VCL threading rules.